# ¿Como guardar los resultados de un for en un array? Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

Lo que tengo es una función que hace que busque y me traiga varios documentos en firebase que cumplan ciertas características.
Gracias al ciclo for lo hace pero al momento de mostrarlo en consola me trae los documentos en arrays separados, lo que busco es que esos arrays me los guarde en uno solo.

```
 buscar(){
  this.dbData.col$('ARTICLES', ref => this.querys(ref));
  }

  async querys(ref){
    for(let x=0;x<=this.posiciones.length-1;x++){
      let snapshot = await ref.where('id_articulo', '==',this.mostrar[0].idArticulos[x].id ).get();    
      snapshot.forEach((doc: { data: () => any[]; }) => {
     
        console.log(doc.data()); //aqui me muestra los resultados en arrays separados
        
      });

      
    }
  
}
```

ejemplo en la consola

```
{id_articulo: "2", id_cliente: "1", caracteristicas: Array(28), articulo: {…}}

{caracteristicas: Array(28), id_cliente: "2", articulo: {…}, id_articulo: "3"}
```

Comment: podrias mostrar el console.log?, para ver la estructura de la respuesta

Comment: si, espera un momento

Comment: Como aclaración, lo que está imprimiendo la consola no son arreglos, son objetos. Por otro lado, cómo es la estructura de la respuesta? Tienes algún conjunto de datos para usar como ejemplo de origen de datos? Y de paso, te recomiendo usar [for of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#forof-statements)

Comment: Te dejo un [pastebin de referencia](https://pastebin.com/P2v9F1tC)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estás haciendo diferentes consultas por lo que te devuelve objetos separados, estas respuestas debes guardarlas en un sólo array.

```
    async querys(ref){
        let arrayResultados: any = [];
        for(let x=0;x<=this.posiciones.length-1;x++){
            let snapshot = await ref.where('id_articulo', '==',this.mostrar[0].idArticulos[x].id ).get();    
            snapshot.forEach((doc: { data: () => any[]; }) => {     
                 arrayResultados.push(doc.data());       
            });      
        }

    }
```